# MaskedEditText не работает

Tags: java, android, xml

Я использую библиотеку [maskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText), ниже возникаю такие ошибки:

[image]

Я скачал библиотеку, потом в еклипсе **File->New->Other->Android** project from existing Code-> Add folder, выбрал copy project into workspace

И потом добавил библиотеку в мой проект:

[image]

А когда я запускаю то ClassNotFoundException

**мойxml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.pppp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pppp.MainActivity" >

    <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        mask:mask="(###) ###-##-##"
                    >
                    </br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ошибки:

```
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pppp/com.example.pppp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:608)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at com.example.pppp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    ... 11 more
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:588)
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    ... 22 more
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.R$styleable
05-30 10:10:38.423: E/AndroidRuntime(32526):    at br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText.<init>(MaskedEditText.java:43)
```

Comment: Не видит либу. Компилировать пробовали? Бывае после запуска приложения, подхватит.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean да, компилировал, ошибки в вопросе(обновил вопрос)

Comment: либа и проект на одном диске находятся?

Comment: Не знаю как в Eclipse, в AndroidStudio можно очищать кеш (бывает помогает). Проект не видит библиотеку. Закомментируйте весь TextEdit-> запустите->раскомментируйте. Должно подхватить. Возможно неправильно подключили.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean да, в eclipse тоже можно очищать проект. Я сделал как вы говорили: удалил весь TextEdit->очистил->запустил, работает. Добавил MaskedEditText-> очистил-> запустил, те же ошибки. Я не понимаю почему так. Я до этого на другом компе подключал эту же библиотеку и все работало, пришел домой сделал все аналогично и такие ошибки. Я над этой проблемой уже часа 3 парюсь(

Comment: @katso да, при добавление либы я скопировал ее `copy project into workspace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась после того как я выбрал новый Workspace(File->Switch Workspace->Other...)

Answer (score 1):

неверный namespace для mask, правильный такой `xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`